# Как интегрировать один проект на yii2 advanced в другой?

Tags: yii2

Есть корпоративный локальный сайт на yii2, шаблон advanced. И мною написан еще один проект yii2 advanced, который, предполагается, должен стать частью того самого сайта (как, например, форум и т п). У этих проектов две разные БД, но с пересекающимися таблицами (одинаковые названия, некоторые поля, но разное содержимое). Каким образом можно интегрировать новый проект на готовый сайт?
Читала про модули на yii2, но, как поняла, там подойдет только проект basic. Как лучше поступить в моем случае?

Comment: Создать отдельную точку входа, например